# How to check if a file exists and create and write a character to it if it doesn't?

Tags: python

I need to check in Python if a file exist and if not to create it and then to write one character in it.

I tried:

```
if os.path.exists(host_file) == False:
    open(host_file, "w").close
```

but I also need to write a character in it.

Is there a way to do this simply without reopening the file?

Comment: Open the file then write to it then close it. Why would you *re*open it?

Comment: Using something like `with open(host_file, 'w') as f:` is preferable. Just write to `f` and then it will be automatically closed when program flow leaves the with block.

Comment: For one thing, `close` is a file method and would need to be *called*. i.e. `myfile.close()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `with...as` keyword, it automatically closes the file.

```py
import os
if not os.path.exists(host_file):
    with open(host_file, "w") as f:
        f.write('ha')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
try:
    with open(host_file, "x") as f:
        f.write('A')
except FileExistsError:
    pass
```

"with" context manager will automatically close the file after writing a character. "x" parameter will not give to open and write to an existing file. This code does not have race condition as between os.path.exists and open functions call file can be created by some other process.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use touch if you just need to create it

```
Path(path_to_file).touch()
```

But if you need to write to file, you will need to open it unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, use `char_to_write` for deaired character.

```py
char_to_write = 'c'

if not os.path.exists(host_file):
  with open(host_file, 'w') as file:
    file.write(char_to_write)
```